# Calculating relative time offset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, time, timespan

I was reading this article about [relative time calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/12#12)

The problem is that the results are wrong due to the time offset. My webpage is Greek.
So how should i modify that function to work correctly, including the GMT+2 or GMT+3 hours offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Greek too, you only need to use the DateTime.**Now**, and not the DateTime.**UtcNow**

And by the way Greek is +2h

Comment: The hosting server resides In U.K. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: @strakastroukas This is depend from what the server have set as the local time. If you have rent it from Greek provider then its probably have set the +2h so there is no problem.

Comment: @strakastroukas The .Now its get the time using the system correction, the UtcNow its getting the time with out that correction. You can use ether UtcNow+2, ether Now and let get the +2 from the system setup.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a problem if you treat everything as UTC time. For example, instead of using `DateTime.Now`, use `DateTime.UtcNow`. Given that you are dealing with relative time, as long as everything is compared against the same base, you should be fine.